# Running database migrations using fastapi, alembic, docker, lambda

Tags: docker, lambda, fastapi

This is something thats been breaking my brain all day, its the last bit that needs doing to get this project up and running.

The project is a fastapi app that is using alembic for managing migrations.

I've setup a lambda function for the app (using a ecr container) and that works well, but I am trying to run migrations on deployments using github actions. I am using aurora(RDS/postgres) for the database and the migrations can only be run using a lambda function from what i've figured out. I can create a second lambda function with a different entrypoint and cmd but struggling to figure out whats needed to get this running as using `alembic upgrade head` as the CMD is not working.

In an idea world i'd be able to do something like `docker exec` to run the migration command during the deployment, but cant find any details on how to do this.

Happy to post any more details on the aws or project setup

Answer (score 1):

So i've managed to figure this out using the following method:

- I created a new migration lambda using the same docker image but the CMD was  `alembic.config.main` instead of `main.handler`
- I then deployed the container and updated the functions as normal using github actions
- Then to run the migrations i ran the following `aws lambda invoke --function-name {FUNCTION_NAME} --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '["--config=/app/task/alembic.ini", "upgrade", "head"]' result.json`